# How to set the the percentage format in google app script table

Tags: google-apps-script

As part of a Google App Script Dashboard, I have the following table:

```
var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
.setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([1,10,15]))
.build();
```

Column 10 is labelled "Percentage of Total" and in my google spreadsheet formatted as "0.00%".  The tableChart however does not take the formatting into account and displays the value as "0.0000"

How does one set the formatting of a specific column in the tableChart to "0.00%"?

Regards
Jann

Comment: I was hopeful that `setColumns(columns, optAdvancedArgs)` or `addColumn(description_object)` would do the trick. I can't get either to work. The documentation for `setColumns` is clearly wrong or incomplete wrt `optAdvancedArgs`, while the `addColumn(object)` method from the Visualization API isn't supported in apps-script. You _could_ opt to use js in an html file stored on drive, and then you'd have access to the richer Visualization API.

Answer (score 0):

A feature request has been added to the issue tracker, [Issue 3063](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3063). Visit and star it to receive updates.