# Trying to convert multiple datasource columns to % percentage formats in tables and graphs

Tags: google-apps-script, format, google-visualization

I am trying to convert data table and chart values to % format; some of my data is numbers and some like datasource [0] [3] and datasource [0] [6] are percentages.

How do I convert it to "%00.00" format? 
I tried using `.setNumberFormat("#.###%);` but I couldn't get it to work.

Below is part of my code:

```
function doGet() {
    var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();
    var ssKey = "0Ao5bdXU44DOpdDg5YVB4UGxpSXI5a1hkcjVhZmlETWc";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssKey);
    var datasource = ss.getRangeByName("a1:ae49").getValues();
    Logger.log(datasource);
    var data = Charts.newDataTable()
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, datasource [0] [0])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [1])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [2])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [3])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [4])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [5])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [6])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [7])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [8])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [9])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [10])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [11])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [12])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [13])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [14])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [15])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [16])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [17])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [18])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [19])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [20])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [21])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [22])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [23])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [24])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [25])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [26])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [27])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [28])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [29])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [30])

    for (i=1;i<=datasource.length-1;i++){
        Logger.log(datasource [i]);
        data.addRow([datasource [i] [0], datasource [i] [1], datasource [i] [2], datasource [i] [3], datasource [i] [4], datasource [i] [5], datasource [i] [6], datasource [i] [7], datasource [i] [8], datasource [i] [9], datasource [i] [10], datasource [i] [11], datasource [i] [12], datasource [i] [13], datasource [i] [14], datasource [i] [15], datasource [i] [16], datasource [i] [17], datasource [i] [18],  datasource [i] [19], datasource [i] [20], datasource [i] [21], datasource [i] [22], datasource [i] [23],  datasource [i] [24], datasource [i] [25], datasource [i] [26], datasource [i] [27], datasource [i] [28], datasource [i] [29], datasource [i] [30]])
    };

    data.build();

    var monthFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Months")
      .build();
    var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
      .setDataTable(data)
      .bind([monthFilter],[tableChart])
      .bind([monthFilter],[tableChart])
      .build();
```

Comment: As an aside, if you're using the entire datasource[i] row, you can use `data.addRow(datasource [i])` instead. I haven't been able to use number formats in tables either. You can use them on the axes of a chart, though.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041102/how-to-set-the-the-percentage-format-in-google-app-script-table. No answer, though.

Comment: @Fred - even better: `var data = ss.getRangeByName("a1:ae49").getDataTable(true);`, and get rid of 41 lines of code from `var datasource` to `data.build()`.

Comment: @Mogsdad Nice, I hadn't noticed that method.

Comment: Hi @Mogsdad when I use var data = ss.getRangeByName("a1:ae49").getDataTable(true); and get rid of the 41 lines of code I get the error message data not defined.

Comment: I put the shorter version of the function in my answer, check it out. Also, you should use `getRange(A1Notation)` instead of `getRangeByName()`, since you are providing a range in A1, not a named range. (I am surprised it worked - and wouldn't trust it to keep working.)

Answer (score 0):

The Charts Service does not support all the options that are available through the Google Visualization API, including column formatting.

A feature request has been added to the issue tracker, [Issue 3063](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3063). Visit and star it to receive updates.

---

Not pertinent to your question, but the Spreadsheet API was recently expanded with a new `Range.getDataTable()` method that can simplify your code dramatically. Here's your function, refactored:

```
function doGet() {
  var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();
  var ssKey = "---Spreadsheet-Id---";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssKey);
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getDataTable(true);

  var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
      .build();
  var monthFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Months")
      .build();
  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
      .setDataTable(data)
      .bind([monthFilter],[tableChart])
      .build();

  var panel = uiApp.createVerticalPanel()
                   .add(monthFilter)
                   .add(tableChart);

  dashboard.add(panel);

  uiApp.add(dashboard);
  return uiApp;
}
```

Comment: Hi thought I would add my entire code; problem is I don't know how to format my data table and charts to have them show as %s, currencys, or month-years:

Comment: Still need to know how to convert .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [3])
to be formatted as a % value "00.00%" and .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [0]) as a Monthname and year format MMMM YYYY

Comment: I understand the problem wrt formatting - there is no way, at this time. See the Issue Tracker item link in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mogsdad I got your rid of my extra lines of code with your help but how would I format the display of my charts var CATVSubsChart = Charts.newColumnChart() .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition() .setColumns([0,3])) .setTitle('CATV Subscribers') .setLegendPosition(Charts.Position.BOTTOM) .build();  to show as % values?

Comment: PLEASE READ THE FIRST PARAGRAPH OF THE ANSWER AND MY PREVIOUS COMMENT. THERE IS NO WAY TO CONTROL THE FORMAT OF THAT DATA.

Comment: Too true! If you figure it out, I'd love an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708392/google-app-script-chart-service-tablechart-column-width-row-height)!

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this, if you must display percentages, would be to approach it from a different angle due to the limited functionality of charts service vs. full visualization api.

I'd suggest creating the table using class flexTable, cell values as strings (to enable formatting) and column headers as triggers for a sort function (this would redraw the table on click so not ideal, but hey it's a workaround!)